# how to embed like button in static fbml page

Tags: facebook

I want to embed a `like` button either using image tag or fb social plugins to let it work same as like button does in my static fbml page. I read somewhere that it can be done with the help of iframe and javascript, can anybody tell me how to implement this on my [landing page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Itempdeal/149879671720485?v=app_4949752878)? I tried with fb:iframe tag also but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've [created a blog post](http://blog.elliotjameschong.com/2011/01/03/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-to-a-fbml-tab/) with code samples on how to add a like button to an FBML tab, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Configure the button (leave the url field blank if you want the button to use your current url)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

And then either use the iframe or xfbml generated code to insert in your html

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks for reply but this xfbml like button plugin works in external page not inside static fbml landing tab because xfbml support for landing tab is now no more.

Comment: so you want a like button in your fbml page?